# android.media.MediaCodec throws exception on queueInputBuffer()

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-mediacodec

I need to convert audio file from PCM to AMR and I tried to make it with MediaCodec from Android API 16+. I got an IllegalStateException on calling it's queueInputBuffer:

```
07-16 19:40:55.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 19:40:55.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19227): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-16 19:40:55.519: E/AndroidRuntime(19227):    at android.media.MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

```
    private static MediaCodec mediaCodec;

    private static void initMediaCodec() {
        mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/3gpp");
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/3gpp", 8000, 1);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 12800);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 8000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
    }

<...>
        initMediaCodec();       
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(fileBuffer); //fileBuffer is ByteBuffer from my input audio file
            mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, fileBuffer.capacity(), 0, 0);
        }
<...>
```

I mentioned that inputBuffers has 4 elements in it with capacity of 320, my audio file buffer might have capacity 96000+.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks!